# Find a 'variable' in a List of json objects

Tags: groovy

Probably a silly question but documentation and search didn't help :(

Trying to 'find' an object in a List of JSON objects(list example shown in the comment):

```
/*jsonList =
    [
    {
    "hide": 2,
    "name": "namespace",
    "type": "constant"
    },
    {
    "hide": 6,
    "label": "dev",
    "type": "variable"
    },
    //more json objects
    ]
    * */
    void searchKeyValueInList(def jsonList, String key, String value) {

        if(!jsonList)
            return

        def dashboardVariable = jsonList.find{variable -> variable.name == value}

        if(dashboardVariable){
            println "Dashboard variable is: ${dashboardVariable}"
        }
    }
```

How do I use the variable **key** instead of a hardcoded 'name' or 'label'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def data = [
    [
        "hide": 2,
        "name": "namespace",
        "type": "constant"
    ],
    [
        "hide": 6,
        "label": "dev",
        "type": "variable"
    ],
]

void searchKeyValueInList(List<Map> jsonList, String key, String value) {
    def dashboardVariable = jsonList?.find { element -> element[key] == value }

    println "Dashboard value for $key is: ${dashboardVariable}"
}

searchKeyValueInList(data, 'label', 'deva')
```